# Join doesnt work properly with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

i have got a problem. I am trying to get ONLY users that last action was in 15 minutes. I am sure that my sql works when i dont use join(tried it), but when i add JOIN or LEFT, RIGHT or other JOINS I get all users, not only active in 15 minutes.
Here is my code

```
function get_logged_users() {
global $dbh;
$users_info = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT
    users.username as `username`,
    users.id as `id`,
    ranks.style as `style`
    FROM `users` 
    LEFT JOIN `ranks` ON users.rank=ranks.id;
    WHERE users.last_login > ?');
$users_info->execute(array(date("Y-m-d H:i:s" ,strtotime( date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." -15 minutes" ))));
$users_info = $users_info->fetchAll();
return $users_info;
```

}

Can anyone help me? :) Thanks!

tables :
[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MlRA.png)

[ranks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CzIv.png)

Comment: can you please provide schemas for users and ranks please?

Comment: sorry, you mean database columns? :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a typo before the `WHERE` clause:

```
...
LEFT JOIN `ranks` ON users.rank=ranks.id;  <---
...
```

There should not be a semicolon (`;` points to the end of the query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql -

```
$users_info = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT
    users.username as `username`,
    users.id as `id`,
    ranks.style as `style`
    FROM `users` 
    JOIN `ranks` ON ranks.id=users.rank
    WHERE users.last_login > ?');
```

Comment: yep, thanks to you too :) so ; in sql means same as in php - end of the code :) and because of that my WHERE didnt work? :)

Comment: yes a semicolon denotes the end of a sql statement so that was not getting executed properly :)